# How to learn album in Telegram bot | Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I have this code, but I need to use another code. Can we give me a example or a some method to learn album? I want to get all files ids.

```
@dp.message_handler(
    IsAdmin,
    state=PostCreation.TextWaiting,
    content_types=ContentType.all
)
async def create_album(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()

    photos = data.get("photos", {})

    file_type = message.content_type
    file_id = None

    if file_type == types.ContentType.ANIMATION:
        file_id = message.animation.file_id
    elif file_type == types.ContentType.PHOTO:
        file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    elif file_type == types.ContentType.VIDEO:
        file_id = message.video.file_id
    elif file_type == types.ContentType.DOCUMENT:
        file_id = message.document.file_id

    has_caption = any(photo.get("caption") for photo in photos.values())

    if not has_caption:
        photo_info = {"file_id": file_id, "file_type": file_type, "caption": message.caption }
    else:
        photo_info = {"file_id": file_id, "file_type": file_type}

    photos[len(photos) + 1] = photo_info

    await state.update_data(photos=photos)
```

`